# Tool to verify commits/releases/etc data after GitLab migration

Tags: git, migration

Currently We are upgrading our on premise gitlab-v8 to Latest Gitlab-v11.
Currently both the versions are running. before using the new gitlab version
We need to validate migration, No. of commits/Releases/Review Comment.

Comment: What do you mean by "to check"? Gitlab-v11 shows you all "merge request/commits/review comment/release/branch", is that not enough?

Comment: Or do you want to make sure that no commit/etc has disappeared during the migration? In that case, do you have both v8 and v11 running at the same time, or are you OK with a database-based check?

Comment: yes. We are OK with database check also.